# What is different between Claims used in ApiResource and Scope in IdentityServer4

Tags: scope, identityserver4, claims

I have created a `ResourceApi` in my `IndetityServer4` something like this:

I have defined a ApiResource called `API 1` and specify directly claims - `name, sub` for this api resource and I've extended this resource and specify two scopes named `Api1.Read` and `Api1.Write` and specify for every scope a specific claims which I need for the specific part of API but I don't understand what is different between Claims used in ApiResource and Scopes?

What does mean `Claims` directly connected in `ApiResource` and Claims which is used in `Scope`?

I have tried restrict UserClaims in ApiResource only for `sub and name` but if I want in `Api1.Write` claim `role` it's sent in access token but in definition of  `Api1` is specify only `name and sub` - why is UserClaims defined in ApiResource?

```
var apiResource = new ApiResource
            {
                Name = "Api1",
                UserClaims = new List<string> { "name", "sub" },

                Scopes = new List<Scope>
                {
                    new Scope
                    {
                        Name = "Api1.Read",
                        UserClaims = new List<string> {"sub", "name"}
                    },
                    new Scope
                    {
                        Name = "Api1.Write",
                        UserClaims = new List<string> {"sub", "name", "role"}
                    }
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [documentation on ApiResource](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/reference/api_resource.html), the `UserClaims` in the `ApiResource` itself will always be included in the access token. If you divide that api in multiple `Scope`'s, the `UserClaims` listed there will be added onto the `UserClaims` specified in the `ApiResource`.